# How to validate two forms on one page in Struts 2 using validate method

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, interceptor

I'm new to Struts2 and I want to validate two form tags on the same page:

1. I have a `userId` and `password` fields on top for `Login` action
2. At center I have another form tag to register a new user

Now my problem is when I apply `addfielderror()` to login i.e (`username` and `password` fields) and fill the registration form as new user won't have `userId` and `password` to login. It shows an error to the login form tag which is blank at that time. That is wrong for that action and it happens for vice-verse. So, what should I do, when I'm doing login it should check only login action and when I'm registering it should check for register action?

**This is my code for `Login` action:**

```
<s:form  method="Post" action="Login">
    <s:textfield   type="text" class=" input-small span2" name="login.Email"  placeholder="Email"></<s:textfield >
    <s:password type="password" class=" input-small span2" name="login.Pass"  placeholder="Password"></ s:password>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button> <br />      
</s:form>
```

**This is Registeration code:**

```
<s:form method="POST" action="Registor">
   <s:textfield class="span1" id="fname" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name"></s:textfield>  
   <s:textfield class="span1" id="Lname" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name"></s:textfield>  
   <s:password class="span2" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"></s:password><br />       
   <s:textfield class="span2" id="email" placeholder="Email ID" name="Email_Id"></s:textfield>
   <br />
   <s:select headerKey="1" id="gender" headerValue="Select Gender" list="#@java.util.HashMap@{'Male':'Male','Female':'Female'}" name="Gender"></s:select><br />                   
   <button type="submit" id="submit" >Submit</button><br />                    
</s:form>
```

**Validate Code:**

```
public void validate() {    
  //This is for login action            
  if((login.getPassword().equals("foobar")){
    addActionMessage(SUCCESS);  
  }else{
    addFieldError("Password", "Password should be greater then 6"); 
  }                         
  //This is for registration action              
  if((user.getPassword() == null) || (user.getPassword().length() < 6)){
    addFieldError("Password", "Password should be greater then 6"); 
  }       
}
```

Now, when I enter correct password like here its `"foobar"` it shows an error to the field on registration form

```
"Password should be greater then 6"
```

instead it should have shown login success message of login action.

**`Struts.xml`:**

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
    <action name="Login" class="org.register.customers.RegisterUserAction" method="getLogin">
        <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">UserLoging.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="Registor"  class="org.register.customers.RegisterUserAction" method="getRegistor">
        <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">RegistorSuccess.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">index.jsp</result> 
    </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: post your code and error can be better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to separate the validation logic for two different actions but you have only one method `validate()` and two actions mapped on methods of the same action class.

As well as you doing *programmatic* validation you should use [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) that performs the prefixed method invocation of `validate()` methods that correspond to the executed action.

Assume you action class extend `ActionSupport`, so you don't have to implement the `validate()` method nor to override it. Then write separate the code

```
 public void validateLogin() {    
   //This is for login action   
   if(login == null) {
     addActionError("Login is null"); 
   } else            
   if("foobar".equals(login.getPassword()){
     addActionMessage(SUCCESS); 
   } else {
     addFieldError("Password", "Password should be greater then 6"); 
   }   
 }   


 public void validateRegister() {
   //This is for registration action
   if(user == null) {  
     addActionError("User is null"); 
   } else            
   if(user.getPassword() == null || user.getPassword().length() < 6) {
     addFieldError("Password", "Password should be greater then 6"); 
   } 
     
 }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer and i got some logic but how should i call this method, should i call this method from my action method like        Public String login(){ validateLogin()  // my other logic    return success  }

Comment: You shouldn't call these methods, the `validation` interceptor will call them while doing `intercept`, all you need is just your action class to implement `Validateable` or even better extend the `ActionSupport` where that interface is implemented by default. Make sure the interceptor is referenced by the actions configuration. The `defaultStack` include it.

Comment: i have extended ActionSupprt in my action class but its not working i am not getting this validate method to work. Can you please tell me in detail, Thanks

Comment: What is your `struts.xml`? What is exactly not working and what do you expect, did you debug it? Were these methods executed?

Comment: Rename file `index.jsp` to `/page.jsp` and update configuration. Also don't post a code in comments. Edit your question and add details.

Comment: the above methods are not getting invoke when i click login or register as the validate method gets invoke. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, the validate method invokes after prefixed methods. What a version of Struts?

Comment: i am using struts-2.3.14.1 version

Comment: You should also check for `null` references, I will update the code.

Comment: On the first form you have `login.` prefix to field name, on the second doesn't have `user.` prefix. Prefixed name means nested beans are in the action. They should be initialized and have getter/setter methods for properties. I have added action errors when such properties aren't initialized. Lately you could get rid of it if you sure they are not `null`.

Comment: Hey, Still its not working, i have my action methods for registor and login as getRegistor() and getLogin() respectively. And as per your sample code form above i wrote like this validategetLogin(){...} and validategetRegistor(){...} but its not going in this method i mean to say its by passing this method, please help me where i am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: The actions in JSP is not mapped to the action configuration, which itself should map the actions to the methods of action class. Make sure the action is called beside the validation and use simple names  `register()` and `login()`.

Comment: Ok, i have corrected the action mapping in struts.xml, now action in JSP is Login() and action in struts.xml is Login() which is map to the action named getLogin() in action class so, what will be the validate method like, validateLogin() or validategetLogin()

Comment: If you have `login()` or `Login()` method the validate method will be `validateLogin()`.